# How to add a new column/key in mongodb at run time?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

In sql we can new column by writing query:
"ALTER TABLE Customers ADD Email varchar(255)"

In nodejs, How can we add new column/key in mongodb, without directly changing the existing Schema?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/#update-a-single-document) to set the new field and insert value.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "Email": "newValue"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

`multi: true` is for updating multiple documents.